# Proper way to instantiate subclasses?

Tags: python, class

So I'm doing a small Pygame programm and I'm trying to structure the stuff in decent look, this is where I stucked.

```
class Screen(object):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.SURFACE = 10 # I need this attribute

class GameMenager(Screen):
    def __init__(self) # Do I need to put the parameters of the super class here?
        super().__init__() # What to put in these parantheses?
```

I want to get the `SURFACE` attribute so I can work with it in the Game class, same with the dimension attributes. What is the proper way to instantiate the classes `Screen` and `GameMenager`?

I red about `super()` but didn't actualy find much information on how to instantiate subclasses when I don't have parameters in the subclass.

Comment: `super(GameMenager, self)`

Comment: As a total side note, are you sure you want GameManager to inherit from Screen? To me, that sounds more like it should be a component of the game manager. As for the __init__(), if you have non-default parameters, make sure the child passes the correct parameters to parent.

Comment: In addition to `super(GameMenager, self)`, you need pass the argument the superclass constructor requires -- so something like `super(GameMenager, self).__init__(width, height)` will be needed. You might want to just add them to `def GameManager.__init__(self, width, height):` and pass them along.

Answer (score 3):

[`super`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#super) is used like this:

```
class Screen(object):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.SURFACE = 10

class GameMenager(Screen):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super(GameMenager, self).__init__(width, height)
```

Now, you can access `Screen.SURFACE`:

```
>>> x = GameMenager(1, 2)  # I just picked 1 and 2 for width and height.
>>> x.SURFACE
10
>>>
```

Comment: You could also have `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` in the subclass and call `super(GameMenager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: @iCodez Doesn't it look bizare to put some random values as the parameters of the super class? For example
`super().init(1, 2)`?

Comment: Note that this is actually incorrect - read [this primer on `super`](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/). particularly you should call `super` from `Screen` also, and always pass all arguments you receive if the functions take different number of args

Answer (score 1):

You don't want `GameMenager` to be a sub-class, here. Rather, you want to pass a screen instance to the `GameMenager` instance:

```
class GameMenager(object):
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen.SURFACE #can do w/e you want with it
    #for example:
    def print_surface(self):
        print self.screen.SURFACE
```

And instantiate it as follows:

```
>>> s = Screen(640, 480) 
>>> gm = GameMenager(s)
>>> gm.print_surface()
10
```

Comment: Why you passes 640, 480, are those just some random values that wont effect the defined parameters of the super class?

Comment: @dragons: yes just random. don't know what you'd want to pass there

Comment: @ Claudiu Actually I just want to use the 'SURFACE' attribute in the subclass. I still need to assign these random parameters of the super class?

Comment: @dragons: oh, you want to do something else. let me modify my answer

Comment: What if I want to use methods from Screen in my GameManager?

Comment: @dragons: in a game manager method, `self.screen` will just point to the screen. you can do whatever you want with it, e.g. `self.screen.method()`